# Where can I find dump from network traffic capture while DNS attack?

Tags: security

I'm searching for dump from network traffic capture like `tcpdump` while DNS attack. With direct classification which record is related to the attack and vice versa.

Comment: While it's fine to post this question here, security.stackexchange.com might be able to help more.